# Strange RAID disk volume usage

Tags: raid, disk, file-size

I have Ubuntu Server 12.04, and my disk is full. I don't know why; my files don't use more than 5GB.

```
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/isw_dahaajfhdc_Sistema2  102G   97G     0 100% /
udev                                 7,7G  4,0K  7,7G   1% /dev
tmpfs                                3,1G  7,2M  3,1G   1% /run
none                                 5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none                                 7,7G     0  7,7G   0% /run/shm
none                                 100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/mapper/isw_dahaajfhdc_Sistema1   94M  123K   94M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sdc                             1,8T  8,8G  1,7T   1% /disco1
/dev/sdd                             1,8T   11G  1,7T   1% /disco2
/dev/sdf                             1,4T  718G  589G  55% /discofilmes
```

/dev/mapper/isw_dahaajfhdc_Sistema2 is full and I really don't know why. This is a RAID disk. What can I do?

Comment: Check hidden files inside your `/home` directory. I recently had problem with `.xsession-errors` which had grown up to 30G size.